# Indentation using multiple org src block

Tags: org-babel, literate-programming

So, say I have a literate org file as follows:

```
#+TITLE: Random Scrap

* Do something
:PROPERTIES:
:tangle: scrap.pl
:comments: org
:END:

#+BEGIN_SRC perl
  sub my_func{
    my $var = pop;
#+END_SRC

some thoughts here..
and the func continues...
#+BEGIN_SRC perl
    my $var1 = $var+1;
 }
#+END_SRC
```

Tangling it to source using `C-c C-v C-t` gives me the following ugly code:

```
# Do something
# :PROPERTIES:
# :tangle: scrap.pl
# :comments: org
# :END:


sub my_func{
  my $var = pop;



# some thoughts here..
# and the func continues...


my $var1 = $var+1;
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is there a simple way to preserve indentation across source blocks, when all of them are going to tangle to a single file?
2. Is there a way to avoid the `# :PROPERTIES: ... # :END:` text to come to the header?

It would be great to have the first feature available. Org mode is a great tool for documenting source code. However, the wrong indentations put it off sometimes. At times, I break the code into fragments that indent properly. At other times, it is required to break code elsewhere, and causes issues like this.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

`(setq org-src-preserve-indentation t)` solved my problem partially. The output tangled file now goes like:

```
# Do something
# :PROPERTIES:
# :tangle: scrap.pl
# :comments: org
# :END:


  sub my_func{
    my $var = pop;



# some thoughts here..
# and the func continues...


    my $var1 = $var+1;
  }
```

However, the comments are still out of indentation. Also, the responsibility of maintaining indentation now lies with me. And the header text is as is...

Any comments/answers? I feel this solution is a bit hacky...

Comment: Wanted to thank you for posting this, it clued me in to the problem I was having with indentation in source block output in HTML publishing.

Comment: I know that this might not be what you want to hear but, maybe you could refactor your code so that you don't need to write a paragraph of thoughts in the middle of the function code? I would consider that to be a "code smell"[1] telling me that I have to break up that function in more manageable parts.    [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell

Comment: @Martín Agreed. That's what I eventually did. Thanks for the comment!